# On which site should I post?

Tags: discussion

A few years ago, I implemented a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay-tolerant_networking project.

This is not exactly mainstream, although not ridiculously esoteric.

At the time, we used $200 embedded microprocessors, but now I would presume that $10 Raspberry Pi Zero Ws would do the job.

Having Googled around, it seems that https://github.com/ibrdtn/ibrdtn/wiki/Install-IBR-DTN#debian-arm is the solution.

However, before committing myself, I want to ask those who are actually developing for DTN on the Pi, in case there is a better alternative.

I am also looking for a low energy solution, as battery life is a factor.

Question: do you think that I would get a better reply here, or on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ (or, possibly even https://gis.stackexchange.com/, or elsewhere) ?

---

[Update] Obviously, I would word any question with some exact requirements, so as not to make it a "what's best question"

Comment: For RPi: Related discussion there - https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/121/9362

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Of course, I can always word my question with some exact requirements, so as not to make it a "what's best question"